# Scraping an XHTML document

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm learning how to use HTML Agility Pack to scrape a page but don't know what to do.

For example, here's one page: http://gtin13.com/query.jsp?query=Hunts

I am hoping to add the following to a database:

Field1: `Hunts Sp Pdg Chc Fdg`
Field2: `14 Oz`
Field3: `Size 12 ct`
Field4: `0027000411766`
Field5: `00-27000-41176-6`
Field6: `027000411766`
Field7: `02700041176`

There are several of these per page.

Here's part of the HTML:

```
<div class="PostContent">
    <b><a href="/product/hunts+sp+pdg+chc+fdg+14+00+oz/">Hunts Sp Pdg Chc Fdg 14.00 Oz</a></b><br />
    Size: 12 ct<br />
    GTIN/EAN-13: 0027000411766 / 00-27000-41176-6<br />
    UPC-A: 027000411766 / 02700041176<br />

    Tags:
    <a href="/tag/hunts/">Hunts</a>, 
     ..<br />
    <br >


    <b><a href="/product/m-hunts+snk+pk+chc+var/">M-Hunts Snk Pk Chc Var</a></b><br />
    Size: 14 oz<br />
    GTIN/EAN-13: 0027000410868 / 00-27000-41086-8<br />
    UPC-A: 027000410868 / 02700041086<br />
    <br >


    <b><a href="/product/hunts+snk+pk+mud+pie+4pk/">Hunts Snk Pk Mud Pie 4pk</a></b><br />
    Size: 14 oz<br />
    GTIN/EAN-13: 0027000412817 / 00-27000-41281-7<br />
    UPC-A: 027000412817 / 02700041281<br />
    <br >
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The logic that determines the Fields from the HTML is not obvious. Could you add some information here?

Comment: Simon, thanks for the reply. I am just trying to break the data between each set of <b> and <br> into f1:description f2:size f3:gtin number f4:ean number f5:upc number and f6:upca number. Maybe there is a beter way than htmlagility I am open to anything.

Comment: I had this problem a while ago with a task i was given at work. The steps I took were to

1. Load in the node
2. Replace the <br />'s with ";"
3. Split the string into an array
4. Decode the array into the useful sections and parse what you want from the string (Maybe whatever is to the right of the : in your case)

Comment: @JRB - the two rows first fields seem different: the 1st one has a "14.00 Oz" after "...Fdg", the second one hasn't. How 14.00 Oz is determined?

Comment: Simon, that is just how the website presents the data.  The firstline is actually a link. I don't need the link to be saved just the other information. I also do not need the "tag" information.

Comment: Simon the info is coming from www.gtin13.com.  I am trying to grab the product description and upc code variations for each product listed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it won't be easy.  Unfortunately the content is laid out awkwardly.  Just gotta chip away at it.  Looking at some of the things listed, I don't see any meaningful way to determine what your `Field2` parts should be.

Given a class to hold your data:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string Size  { get; set; }
    public string Gtin  { get; set; }
    public string Ean13 { get; set; }
    public string Upc   { get; set; }
    public string UpcA  { get; set; }
}
```

To get the data:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://gtin13.com/query.jsp?query=Hunts");

var sections = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='PostContent']/b");
var result = new List<Data>();
foreach (var header in sections)
{
    var data = new Data();
    data.Name = header.InnerText.Trim();
    var currentField = header.NextSibling.NextSibling;

    var sizeMatch = Regex.Match(currentField.InnerText.Trim(), @"Size: (.+)");
    if (sizeMatch.Success)
    {
        data.Size = sizeMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        currentField = currentField.NextSibling.NextSibling;
    }

    var gtinMatch = Regex.Match(currentField.InnerText.Trim(), @"GTIN/EAN-13: (\S+) / (\S+)");
    if (gtinMatch.Success)
    {
        data.Gtin = gtinMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        data.Ean13 = gtinMatch.Groups[2].Value;
        currentField = currentField.NextSibling.NextSibling;
    }

    var upcMatch = Regex.Match(currentField.InnerText.Trim(), @"UPC-A: (\S+) / (\S+)");
    if (upcMatch.Success)
    {
        data.Upc = upcMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        data.UpcA = upcMatch.Groups[2].Value;
    }

    result.Add(data);
}
```